# Как считать значения из текстового файла и положить их в ArrayList массивов?

Tags: java, arraylist, многомерные-списки

Есть текстовый файл, в который записаны числа (каждое с новой строки) в таком формате:

```
1075   
5018   
6542   
1456
```

и так далее.
Хочу создать `ArrayList` массивов и каждый массив этого листа заполнить цифрами из строки. То есть в первом массиве будут цифры `{1,0,7,5}`, во втором `{5,0,1,8}` и так далее. И не знаю, как это сделать наиболее кратко. Подкиньте вариантов, пожалуйста.

```
List<int[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
    int[]square1=new int[4];
    int[]square2=new int[4];
    int[]square3=new int[4];
    int[]square4=new int[4];
    int[]square5=new int[4];
    
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("/Users/Anastasiya/Desktop/test.txt"));
String s = "";
while((s = sc.nextLine())!=null) {
    if (!s.isEmpty()) {
        for(int j = 0; sc.hasNextInt();j++){
            square1[j]=sc.nextInt();
        }
        list.add(square1);
    }
```

Но таким методом у меня, понятное дело, заполняется лишь первый массив. И вот как с помощью цикла заполнить все массивы?

Comment: так вы одно и то же добавляете в список `list.add(square1);`

Answer (score 1):

Если по минимуму, то вы можете создать массив внутри цикла и каждый раз переменная будет создаваться заново. А вот добавленный внутрь списка массив сохранится т.к. ссылка на него не будет стерта.

```
List<int[]> list = new ArrayList<>();

Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("/Users/Anastasiya/Desktop/test.txt"));
String s = "";
while((s = sc.nextLine())!=null) {
    if (!s.isEmpty()) {
        int[] square = new int[4]; //изменение, используется одна переменная
        for(int j = 0; sc.hasNextInt();j++){
            square[j]=sc.nextInt();
        }
        list.add(square); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
List<int[]> list = new ArrayList<>();

Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("/Users/Anastasiya/Desktop/test.txt"));
// цикл, пока есть числа
while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
  // считали число
  int num = sc.nextInt();
  // создали новый массив
  int[] cur = new int[4];
  // добавили его в список
  list.add(cur);
  for (int i = 3; i >= 0; i--) {
    // Нарезаем цифры
    cur[i] = num % 10;
    num /= 10;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете java8, то с этим очень легко и красиво справятся Stream`ы и классы для работы с файлами из пакета nio

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    List<int[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> strings = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("/Users/Anastasiya/Desktop/test.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    strings.forEach(s -> list.add(Arrays.stream(s.split("")).mapToInt(Integer::valueOf).toArray()));

    list.forEach(arr -> {
        for (int value : arr) {
            System.out.print(value);
        }
        System.out.println();
    });
}
```